# AI platform no detailed information - Internal error occurred for the current attempt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I'm running hyper-parameter tuning job using custom container. When I run the job for small number of steps everything works fine. The problem is for higher numer of steps (which means longer jobs) - they end with not very informative message "Internal error occurred for the current attempt.".

I have 3 suspicions:

1. The configuration of my machines is not optimal - my job does a lot of computation with numpy. I've noticed that CPU usage of the master machine, parameter servers and workers are around 100% for all trials. To be honest I'd expected it to be 100% only for workers (or 100% only for master because I don't run distributed training). So it means that I don't quite understand how these different machine types are used in hyper-parameter tuning. I'm was not able to find any detailed resources about it.
2. The intermediate data are saved every few steps. Maybe I'm saving too much? Is there a way to check storage usage of the machines?
3. There is a problem with Google Infrastructure.

Below is beginning of my configuration file.

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: n1-highcpu-16
  workerType: n1-highcpu-16
  parameterServerType: n1-standard-4
  evaluatorType: n1-standard-4
  workerCount: 4
  parameterServerCount: 1
  evaluatorCount: 1
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MINIMIZE
    hyperparameterMetricTag: "cumulative_regret"
    maxTrials: 108
    maxParallelTrials: 4
    enableTrialEarlyStopping: False
    algorithm: GRID_SEARCH
```

Comment: Can you send an email with your job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com please? Internally, we try to fix all the service issues causing job failures, but it may take some time to release fixes. We would like to work with you to unblock your use case sooner.